# Dart Flutter The method 'init' isn't defined for the type 'OneSignal'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, onesignal

I'm trying to make a system of sending notifications to the phone with OneSignal.

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kelimeogrenmeuygulamasi/arayuzEkrani.dart';
import 'package:onesignal_flutter/onesignal_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Firebase.initializeApp();
  OneSignal.shared.init("YOUR ONESIGNAL APP ID", iOSSettings: {
    OSiOSSettings.autoPrompt: false,
    OSiOSSettings.inAppLaunchUrl: false
  });
  runApp(mainApp());
}
```

In this code, I get an error in the `init` part.

**Error:**

[image]

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code as _text_ not as an image.

Comment: @MendelG It's already attached.

Comment: Please include your imports as text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am facing same error, i was searching and found out that setAppId instead of init maybe works, so try it

Answer (score 0):

use below code

```
void configOneSignel()
{
  OneSignal.shared.setAppId('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-app-id-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
}
```